# Displaying a Google Map with JS code works in Chrome, but won't work when pasted into Wordpress

Tags: java, wordpress, google-maps

I'm not much a coder (and I'm new to this site), would this be an appropriate place to ask why a piece of javascript code displays a map properly under Google Chrome, but when that same piece of code is pasted into Wordpress, it longer displays a Google Map?

This code works in the three browsers I've tested it in, but won't work when pasted into Wordpress:

```
<h3>Anchorage Birding Guide</h3>
Greater Anchorage Area – Officially called the Municipality of Anchorage with an estimated 298,695 residents in 2015.  It is Alaska's most populous city and contains more than 40 percent of the state's population; among the fifty (50) states, only New York has a higher percentage of residents who live in its' most populous city.

<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchorage,_Alaska" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Anchorage</a> is located in the south-central portion of <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Alaska</a> at the terminus of the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook_Inlet" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Cook Inlet</a> on a peninsula formed by the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knik_Arm" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Knik Arm</a> to the north and the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnagain_Arm" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Turnagain Arm</a> to the south.  The city limits span 1,961.1 square miles (5,079.2 km<sup>2</sup>) which encompass the urban core, a joint military base - <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Base_Elmendorf%E2%80%93Richardson" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Joint Base Elmendorf-Richardson</a>, several outlying communities, and almost all of <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chugach_State_Park" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Chugach State Park</a>.
<ol>
    <li>
        Metropolitan Anchorage Area
        <ol>
            <li>
                Coastal Areas
                <ol>
                    <li>Port of Anchorage</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2543" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Ship Creek Mouth</a></li>
                    <li>Elderberry Park</li>
                    <li>Westchester Lagoon Area</li>
                    <li>Lynn Ary Park</li>
                    <li>Point Woronzoff</li>
                    <li>Point Campbell Park</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2141" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Carr-Gottstein Park</a></li>
                    <li>Kincaid Park</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2669" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Campbell Creek Estuary Natural Area</a></li>
                    <li>John’s Park</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>
                Coast to Mountain Belt
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2750" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Windsong Park</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2821" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Cuddy Family Midtown Park</a></li>
                    <li>East Chester</li>
                    <li>Spenard Crossing</li>
                    <li>Hillside Park</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2349" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Cheney Lake</a></li>
                    <li>Goose Lake</li>
                    <li>DeLong Lake</li>
                    <li>Campbell Tract/Far North Bicentennial Park</li>
                    <li>Russian Jack Springs Park</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2784" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Tikishla Park</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2828" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Arnold L. Muldoon Park</a></li>
                    <li>University Lake</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2409" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Baxter Bog Park</a></li>
                    <li>Chester Creek Greenbelt Park</li>
                    <li>Davenport Fields??</li>
                    <li>Government Hill</li>
                    <li>R Street Alley</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2825" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Connors Lake Park</a></li>
                    <li>Pop Carr Memorial Park</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2772" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Al Miller Memorial Park</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2793" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Little Campbell Lake Park</a></li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>
                Mountainous Areas
                <ol>
                    <li>Potter Valley</li>
                    <li>Bear Valley</li>
                    <li>Glen Alps</li>
                    <li>Stuck-again Heights</li>
                    <li>Arctic Valley</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        Areas South of Anchorage
        <ol>
            <li>Potter’s Marsh</li>
            <li>McHugh Creek</li>
            <li>Indian</li>
            <li>Bird Creek</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2860" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Windy Corner Trailhead</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2855" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Bird Point</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2833" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Girdwood Junction</a></li>
            <li>Road Side Lakes South of Girdwood</li>
            <li>20 Mile River</li>
            <li>Whittier Road Junction</li>
            <li>Portage Creek</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        Areas North of Anchorage
        <ol>
            <li><a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2840" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Eagle River Nature Center</a></li>
            <li>North Eagle River</li>
            <li>Birchwood</li>
            <li>Chugiak</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
<h4></h4>
<h4></h4>
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 900px; height: 550px; resize: none; max-width: 100%;">
    <div id="embed-map-display2" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD0A1XbJ9TOjfFEA3FtPxM1gKzRyEKzTQg&callback=initMap">
        </script>        
<script>
    "use strict";
var map;
var activeInfoWindow;
var marker = [];
var infoWnd = [];
function initMap() {
    var mapcenter = { lat: 61.1722, lng: -149.1885 };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('embed-map-display2'),
    {
    zoom: 9,
    center: mapcenter,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    scaleControl: true,
    fullscreenControl: true
    });

    var locations =
    [
        [{ lat: 61.2299, lng: -149.8295 }, 'Elmendorf Fish Hatchery', 'Elmendorf Fish Hatchery'],
        [{ lat: 61.1540, lng: -150.0537 }, 'Kincaid Park', 'Kincaid Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1773, lng: -149.8905 }, 'Business Park Wetlands', 'Business Park Wetlands'],
        [{ lat: 61.1789, lng: -149.8523 }, 'Waldron Pond', 'Waldron Pond'],
        [{ lat: 61.1659, lng: -149.7657 }, 'Far North Bicentennial Park', 'Far North Bicentennial Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1664, lng: -149.6920 }, 'Dome Trailhead', 'Dome Trailhead'],
        [{ lat: 61.3394, lng: -149.5627 }, 'Eagle River Duck Pond', 'Eagle River Duck Pond'],
        [{ lat: 61.4491, lng: -149.3705 }, 'Thunderbird Falls Trailhead', 'Thunderbird Falls Trailhead'],
        [{ lat: 61.2118, lng: -149.9159 }, 'R Street Alley', 'R Street Alley'],
        [{ lat: 61.2293, lng: -149.8865 }, 'Al Miller Memorial Park', 'Al Miller Memorial Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.2046, lng: -149.9055 }, 'Spenard Crossing', 'Spenard Crossing'],
        [{ lat: 61.2022, lng: -150.0208 }, 'Point Woronzof', 'Point Woronzof'],
        [{ lat: 61.1848, lng: -149.8078 }, 'University Lake Park', 'University Lake Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.9294, lng: -149.3465 }, 'Bird Point', 'Bird Point'],
        [{ lat: 61.2083, lng: -149.9208 }, 'Westchester Lagoon', 'Westchester Lagoon'],
        [{ lat: 61.0781, lng: -149.8271 }, 'Potters Marsh', 'Potters Marsh'],
        [{ lat: 61.2465, lng: -149.5360 }, 'Arctic Valley', 'Arctic Valley'],
        [{ lat: 61.1788, lng: -149.8992 }, 'Pop Carr Memorial Park', 'Pop Carr Memorial Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1634, lng: -150.0233 }, 'Little Campbell Lake Park', 'Little Campbell Lake Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.2177, lng: -149.9072 }, 'Elderberry Park', 'Elderberry Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1747, lng: -150.0320 }, 'Point Campbell Park', 'Point Campbell Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1054, lng: -149.8815 }, 'Johns Park', 'Johns Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1951, lng: -149.7389 }, 'Arnold L. Muldoon Park', 'Arnold L. Muldoon Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.2064, lng: -149.7883 }, 'Russian Jack Springs Park', 'Russian Jack Springs Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1846, lng: -149.8786 }, 'Cuddy Family Midtown Park', 'Cuddy Family Midtown Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1968, lng: -149.8211 }, 'Goose Lake Park', 'Goose Lake Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1639, lng: -149.9539 }, 'Delong Lake Park', 'Delong Lake Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.2018, lng: -149.9466 }, 'Lynn Ary Park', 'Lynn Ary Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1428, lng: -149.7432 }, 'Hillside Park', 'Hillside Park'],
        [{ lat: 61.1143, lng: -149.9386 }, 'Carr-Gottstein Park', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.2002, lng: -149.7620 }, 'Cheney Lake Park', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.1883, lng: -149.7570 }, 'Baxter Bog Park', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.1322, lng: -149.9664 }, 'Campbell Creek Estuary', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.1635, lng: -150.0233 }, 'Little Campbell Lake Park', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.2025, lng: -149.8255 }, 'Tikishla Park', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.2291, lng: -149.8861 }, 'Al Miller Memorial Park', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.2078, lng: -149.7260 }, 'Windsong Park', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.2231, lng: -149.8991 }, 'Ship Creek Mouth', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.1845, lng: -149.8786 }, 'Cuddy Family Midtown Park', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.1713, lng: -149.9393 }, 'Connors Lake Park', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 61.1951, lng: -149.7388 }, 'Arnold L. Muldoon Park', 'mycontent'],
        [{ lat: 60.9402, lng: -149.1719 }, 'Girdwood Junction', '<a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2833" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Girdwood Junction&nbsp</a>'],
        [{ lat: 61.2346, lng: -149.2713 }, 'Eagle River Nature', '<a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2840" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Eagle River Nature     Center&nbsp</a>'],
        [{ lat: 60.9294, lng: -149.3465 }, 'Bird Point', '<a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2855" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Bird Point&nbsp</a>'],
        [{ lat: 60.9848, lng: -149.6045 }, 'Windy Corner Trailhead', '<a href="http://www.anchorageaudubon.org/?p=2860" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Windy Corner Trailhead&nbsp</a>']
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations[i][0],
            map: map,
        });
        marker[i].index = i;

        infoWnd[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infoWnd[i].setContent(locations[i][2]);
        infoWnd[i].clicked = false;

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'mouseover', function () {
            if (activeInfoWindow != null) {
                activeInfoWindow.close();
                activeInfoWindow.clicked = false;
            };
            infoWnd[this.index].open(map, marker[this.index]);
            activeInfoWindow = infoWnd[this.index];
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'mouseout', function () {
            if (infoWnd[this.index].clicked == false) infoWnd[this.index].close();
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function () {
            if (activeInfoWindow != null) {
                activeInfoWindow.close();
                activeInfoWindow.clicked = false;
            };
            infoWnd[this.index].open(map, marker[this.index]);
            infoWnd[this.index].clicked = true;
            activeInfoWindow = infoWnd[this.index];
        });
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to paste the code that you are trying to use? Also if it is using google maps make sure that you include all the correct javascript files.

Comment: I'll paste the code.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Standard HTML list from line 1 to line 97.  The js code starts at about line 98 with "var map".  The code just populates a google map with markers.

Comment: The code works properly when saved as an html file and opened in Chrome, IE, and Edge.  Fails to work when pasted into a Wordpress blog.